# windows 2008 r2 internet sharing via network bridge

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking

I have 2 PCs running windows, namely A and B.

A has 2 network adapters A-NIC1 and A-NIC2

B has 1 network adapter B-NIC1.

A-NIC1 is connected to the company network and it can access the internet, The IP address is something like "192.168.1.XXX".

I want to connect B-NIC1 to A-NIC2 using a straight RJ-45 lan cable and do some network configuration in windows 2008 R2 running on the PC A. I hope the PC B can access the internet via this lan cable connection to the PC A.

Is it possible to achieve my goal in this way?

If yes, how to setup the windows 2008 network? I prefer using network bridge instead of NAT?

If no, what are other method (without adding routers or other equipments)?

Comment: Can you assign PC B an IP address inside the 192.168.1.xxx LAN? If so, just bridge the two network interfaces on PC A.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you select both A-NIC1 and A-NIC2 right click and select bridge networks. you then just conncet A-NIC2 to your B-NIC1.

Mind though that normally you should use a cross over cable instead of a straight one. It might work if your network cards have autosensing.

Comment: After selecting bridge network include both A-NIC1 and A-NIC2, the "network bridge" has no internet access. It shows "unidentified network". When connect B-NIC1 to A-NIC2, there is no internet connection.

Comment: Well there is a utp cable in A-NIC1 right that can connect to internet?

Comment: yes, A-NIC1 is connected to the internet but when I bridge A-NIC1 and A-NIC2 together, the A-NIC1 lost internet connection.

Comment: Did you configure the IP's?

Comment: the PC A IP is assigned by DHCP (192.168.1.6), the PC B IP is assigned manually with a non-conflicting IP (192.168.1.10) on the network. The router is able to assign IP address from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.100.

Comment: so if you have Ip's and a gateway from your DHCP server I don't see a reason why you would not have internet connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

leave A-NIC1 IP assigned by DHCP and assign B-NIC1 IP manually to something outside the router's range for DHCP, then bridge A-NIC1 and A-NIC2. if the range is 192.168.0.2-100, then PC B should be 192.168.0.101-254 assuming the subnetmask is 255.255.255.0 (network is 192.168.1.0/24).